# ElasticSearch - Geo Spatial search on location array

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am creating an index with two types Restaurant and Branch with Spring Data. Restaurant has many branches as nested type. When I create this mapping, Spring Data / ElasticSearch automatically converts the location field inside the Branch type as latitude , longitude array, hence geo spatial query is not possible. Here it is:

I want to perform a search on branch.location for geo spatial search, but elastic search is not treating location as geopoint, rather a string array, hence it is not possible, please suggest what I need to do or where I am getting wrong.

```
class Restaurant {
    @Field( type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<Branch> branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();
}

class Branch {
   private GeoPoint location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using

**org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint**

And not

*org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoPoint*

Alternatively (and perhaps better), define the mapping yourself instead of letting spring/elasticsearch do it for you.